# Confidence interval of a regression

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a regression x(t) = at+b, number of trials,  and R2 of the regression. How do I find the value and 95% confidence interval for the value of V = x/t?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect you found your regression values with some software? What was it (it probably also has an in-built standard-deviation function)?

Comment: No, the formula is given

Comment: All right then, which parameter(s) do you then want to find the confidence interval on?

Comment: @Lovsovs oh, appols trying to find x/t, I modified the question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is interested, here is the solution:

V = a +/- da

da = t(percentile, N-2) sigma

sigma = a* sqrt( (1/R^2 - 1)/(N-2))